# Solving the indefinite integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, fractions, substitution

I want to solve the following indefinite integral:
(1) $$\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} dx$$
completing the square:
(2) $$=\int \frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}} dx$$
Substitution:
(3) $$u=\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3}$$ brings:
(4) $$dx=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} du$$
(5) $$= \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du$$
Then getting standard integral
(6) $$= \arctan(u)$$
and solving the integral and substitute back is not the problem. But I have a problem understanding the substitution in step (3). I don't know where the $\sqrt 3$ beneath the fraction line comes from and how the formula ends in the standard integral in (5) on the right side. Could someone explain these steps in a bit more detail?

Comment: **Try** $u=x+\frac{1}{2}$ or $u=2x+1$ and see what happens. It may work it may not. Just a thought. Often proofs are worked out in a slightly ad-hoc and messy way, then the mathematician will tidy up his/her proof to present the most elegant form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}=\left(\frac{2x+1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{4}\left(\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+1\right)=\frac{3}{4}(u^2+1).$$
Since $\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}=u$, we have $$\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)'dx=du$$ or $$\frac{2}{\sqrt3}dx=du$$ or
$$dx=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}du.$$
Thus, $$\int\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}dx=\int\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}(u^2+1)}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}du=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\int\frac{1}{1+u^2}du.$$

Answer (score 1):

We may take a more general approach here. Consider the integral
$$I(x;a,b,c)=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{ax^2+bx+c}=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+g}$$
Here $g=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$. If we assume that $4ac>b^2$, then we may make the substitution $x+\frac{b}{2a}=\sqrt{\frac{g}{a}}\tan u$ which gives 
$$I(x;a,b,c)=\sqrt{\frac{g}{a}}\int\frac{\sec^2u\,\mathrm du}{g\tan^2u+g}$$
$$I(x;a,b,c)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{ag}}$$
$$I(x;a,b,c)=\frac2{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\arctan\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}+C$$
Plug in $a=b=c=1$ to get your integral